# How to merge Let's Encrypt added server block to already existing proxy_pass server block correctly?

Tags: proxy, nginx, https, wireguard

Originally I had a simple server block that acts as a proxy to my WireGuard tunnel, but then I installed Let's Encrypt and it added a server block of its own.

Everything still works well, the only problem is that HTTP is not redirected to HTTPS although Let's Encrypt added it (but HTTPS does work if I manually enter that in the address).

I think that's because the original server block that acts as a `proxy_pass` intercepts the requests before. Though I could not edit it in such way that they would both work as intended.

This is what I currently have:

```
# original server block for WireGuard
server { 
    server_name mydomain www.mydomain ;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host-Real-IP  $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://10.8.0.22:80;
    }

# added by Let's Encrypt
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain /privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name mydomain www.mydomain;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Can I merge the two? Or that's not even the issue why HTTP is not redirected to HTTPS?
Thanks

Comment: Put the part of your code where the Let's Encrypt routine is called.

Comment: I am not sure where to get that part of code, I simply followed this guide and it created it automatically: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Can you check which ports Let's Encrypt uses to generate the code and if they are closed on your PC, or are they being blocked by your firewall?

Comment: Which code? Please help me find out where it is

Comment: You can combine this into one server block like so: server { listen 80; listen 443 default_server ssl; # other directives }....you need to check this with Let's Encrypt support